# Has any Dark Force user/ally ever said "May the Force be with you"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

This saying/blessing seems to me just as applicable for someone allied with the Dark Force as a Light Force ally as the statement appears to be Force-neutral. By Dark Force user, I mean it (or similar words) being said in the business of Dark Force-leaning activity, not someone who may have said it as a Light Force user and then went to the Dark Side (and never said afterwards).

Either Canon or Legends examples are acceptable.

Comment: Does "while pretending to be a user of the Light side" count?

Comment: @MikeScott - No. They have to "mean it" and not simply say it as part of a deception.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/May_the_Force_be_with_you/Legends ? Doesn't look like any of the Sith have said that exact phrase, though Vader saying "Remember the Dark Side is always with you" to Starkiller is an interesting one.

Comment: The closest that comes to mind for me is "The Force is strong with this one" in episode 4

Comment: I think Dark Side philosophy usually runs more along the lines of, "If the Force isn't with you, you're a loser."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not that exact phrase, to my knowledge, but the closest I think we get is at the end of Attack of the Clones, in this interchange (taken from [wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_%E2%80%93_Attack_of_the_Clones#Count_Dooku)):

> **Dooku**: The Force is with us, Master Sidious.
>   **Darth Sidious**: Welcome home, Lord Tyranus. You have done well.

On a side note, it's an interesting idea that this particular phrase hasn't been spoken between Sith, especially when it has been spoken between a non-Force user (Han) to a Force user (Luke). Consider, though, that well-wishing to someone else is a selfless act. This is not the type of sentiment normally associated with the Sith.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find a use of that phrase by a dark side user in any canon book. I can't find that *exact* phrase in any of my Legends books, either. However, the Legends novel [*Darth Plagueis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_(novel)) contains a slight variation of the phrase from Palpatine to a young Anakin Skywalker. It occurs at a time coinciding with the end of Episode I:

> [Palpatine] cut his gaze to Anakin. “I didn’t have an opportunity on Naboo to thank you, young Skywalker. Your actions were nothing less than extraordinary. **May the Force ever be as strong with you.**”
>
> “Thank you, sir,” Anakin said in a quiet voice.
>
> <sub>**p. 367**</sub>

This was not a use of the phrase from dark side user to dark side user, but Palpatine was undoubtedly wishing that the dark side of the Force would be strong with Anakin so that Anakin would become a powerful new apprentice for Palpatine. Palpatine was already planning to turn Anakin to the dark side at this point because the book ends just a few paragraphs later with:

> “As I told you on Naboo, Anakin,” [Palpatine] said finally, “we will continue to follow your career with great interest.”
>
> *And assure that it culminates in the ruination of the Jedi Order and the reascendancy of the Sith!*
>
> <sub>**p. 368**</sub>

Comment: I'd say this is a little-more-than-half answer given how Anakin turns out, but as you mention, there might not be any more than that. +1