# Why do members of the dark side seldom say "May the force be with you/us" to each other?

Tags: star-wars

The phrase "May the force be with you" does not exclusively belong to the Jedi. But members of the dark side seem to be reluctant in saying "May the force be with you/us" to each other. Why? Don't they want the force to be with them?

Comment: This is a dupe. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/163428/54605

Comment: "Why would I want the Force to be with that other guy?  I want the Force to be with ME, thank you very much.  Just me.  Not that guy, me."

Comment: I thought _The Last Jedi_ established that concepts like "light side" and "dark side" are Jedi things, Jedi ways of thinking about it - the Force itself doesn't really have two halves. It's all just how in you handle it.

Comment: cuz they are jerks generally

Comment: I think in the old legends cannon the sith viewed the force as something to be conquered and used rather than as a All-powerful force to be respected. (though i can't think of a specific example at this time)

Comment: Superstitious nonsense. If one wants the force, one must seize it!

Comment: @iMerchant Not really a dupe, but at the same time seriously doubt there's anything in canon explaining it so the question calls for an opinion which may make it outside the scope of the site.

Comment: These aren't dupes. Neither of the answers in the linked question answer the question asked here, they merely list occurrences where a Sith has said something similar.

Comment: *"On a side note, it's an interesting idea that this particular phrase hasn't been spoken between Sith, especially when it has been spoken between a non-Force user (Han) to a Force user (Luke). Consider, though, that well-wishing to someone else is a selfless act. This is not the type of sentiment normally associated with the Sith."*. It's not a great answer, but [it's there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/163474/5184) on the original.

Comment: Dark Side users say “Live long and prosper” instead, although they always then turn away, contort their face into an evil grimace, and say *“Not!”* under their breath.

Answer (score 5):

You can read the following on [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/May_the_Force_be_with_you)

> "May the Force be with you" was a phrase used to wish an individual or group good luck or good will, one that expressed the speaker's wish that the Force work in the favor of the addressee. The phrase was often used as individuals parted ways or in the face of an impending challenge.

**Jedi / Light side**

The sentence

> "Wish that The Force work in the favor of the addressee"

shows how the relation between that power and a Jedi works. The easy answer would be that for the Jedi, the Force is a power that does not belong to him. It's an energy that flows through everything, big and small, far and near, an energy that bind and guide him through his destiny. So the sentence is wishing for someone to have a good future planned by the force.

It would be like petting a cat, the Jedi way would be to sit and wait for the cat to come to him because he wants the light side user to pet it.

**Sith / Dark side**

On the other end of the spectrum however, the Sith has a different relationship with the Force. He does not want to follow what the Force has planned for him. Self-centered as he is, he wants to possess and control everything, be it the power, the resources of all the galaxy or his own destiny.
He doesn't want to follow the will of the Force, he wants to tame it, to bend it to his will.

If he wanted to pet the cat from earlier, the Sith way would be to Force-Pull the animal to him and then throw it in a cage for later petting.

So the reason the Sith will never, NEVER use that sentence is because it goes against everything he believes in. It would be like acknowledging that there is something controlling him, something he has no power over and that is not a fact his pride and arrogance would ever accept.

Answer (score 1):

Any answer is going to be opinion based

With that being Jedi see the force as a living being, the force is in everything, the force makes things happen for its own reasons.

The Sith ultimately see the force as a tool to use so saying "may the force be with you" would be like saying "may the screwdriver be with you"

see this answer  [Why do the Jedi say "May the Force be with you"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/why-do-the-jedi-say-may-the-force-be-with-you?rq=1)

This question is not quite a duplicate but its kinda close

Comment: So why do they seldom say it? You've not really answered the question, or made a good point on why it would be similar to saying "May the screwdriver be with you"

Comment: I would say that the Sith are more focused on dominating and using the force as a tool; rather than, A living thing that can be with you, in the form of alliance or character alignment. A Jedi would look at a Herculean task and wish for the force to be "inline with their will" (with them) while a Sith would want the force to work in for them. The distinction is small but significant.

Comment: May the Long Island Iced Tea be with you.